# Re-nesting a Json output in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json output in a loop and at the end of the loop I need to assign a unique key to the json. Something like the following :

```
out = {"34267":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1456012800000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1456012800000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":621,"Visit_Ids":[116644],"RFMClass":"244","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692},"101":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1423958400000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1423958400000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":992,"Visit_Ids":[1883],"RFMClass":"444","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692},"8877":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1459900800000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1459900800000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":576,"Visit_Ids":[141943],"RFMClass":"144","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692}}
```

But assign something like `out_final = {32: out}`, 
makes the inner Json a string like the following :

```
{32: '{"34267":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1456012800000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1456012800000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":621,"Visit_Ids":[116644],"RFMClass":"244","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692},"101":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1423958400000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1423958400000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":992,"Visit_Ids":[1883],"RFMClass":"444","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692},"8877":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1459900800000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1459900800000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":576,"Visit_Ids":[141943],"RFMClass":"144","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692}}'}
```

This makes searching for a specific value impossible. Is there a way where I can assign the unique key without losing the inner structure.

Like the following :

```
{32: {"34267":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1456012800000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1456012800000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":621,"Visit_Ids":[116644],"RFMClass":"244","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692},"101":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1423958400000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1423958400000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":992,"Visit_Ids":[1883],"RFMClass":"444","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692},"8877":{"Annual Expenditure":250,"Annual Frequency":1,"Avg days":null,"First visit":1459900800000,"Frequency":1,"Last visit":1459900800000,"Merchants":32,"Monetory":250,"Recency":576,"Visit_Ids":[141943],"RFMClass":"144","AvgLTV":13305.7692307692}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is create nested dictionary and then convert to `json` by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26057360/2901002):

```
d = df.set_index('Guest').to_dict(orient='index')
d_final = {32: j}

import json
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(d, fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply escape `{` with `{{` as this:

```
out_final = '{{32:{}}}'.format(out)
```